# Node doesn't write to the file.

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to modify the [plugin](https://github.com/btd/mocha-better-spec-reporter/blob/master/index.js), to write to the file rather than console.

For that I have created a file stream in node like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileName = "mochareport.html"

var writeStream;
writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        log.warn('Cannot write HTML Report\n\t' + err.message);
    } else {
        log.debug('HTML report written to "%s".', fileName);
    }
});
```

on the run, it create the file. But on the line [132]:

```
if(failures.length) that.writeFailures(failures);
```

it calls a method called `writeFailures`, so I have added a line like this in the `writeFailures` method:

```
writeStream.write("Hello")
```

But the text `Hello` doesn't get written to the file.

What mistake I'm doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs.createWriteStream()` doesn't accept a callback. It returns a writable stream that you call `.write()` on and listen for events on (mostly `finish` if you're interested in that).

If you want to just write once (e.g. open, write, and then close) and not continue writing (e.g. open, write, write, ..., close), then you could instead use something like [`fs.writeFile()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) or [`fs.appendFile()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_filename_data_options_callback) (depending on your desired behavior), both of which accept a callback that gets called when the file is closed.